# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException when using sbt docker:publishLocal

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I created a new project with sub-projects and enabled dockerPlugin for each sub-project.
However, when I execute `sbt docker:publishLocal`, I got across the exception as below:

```
[info] Wrote D:\ProgrammingStyle\code\milkyway\frontend\target\scala-2.11\frontend_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2368)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2410)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.com$typesafe$sbt$packager$docker$DockerPlugin$$makeAdd(DockerPlugin.scala:152)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$8.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:79)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$8.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:70)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (frontend/*:dockerCommands) java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
[error] \
[error]  ^
```

I'm wondering if there is a solution for this problem or I needed to change my structure of project?

my build.sbt is as below:

```
name in ThisBuild := "milkyWay"

// TODO Set your version here
version in ThisBuild := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.6"

lazy val `frontend` = (project in file("frontend")).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

lazy val `backend` = (project in file("backend")).
  enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging).
  enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
```

And these are empty projects. I have only the basic files in frontend. I'm using sbt-native-packager 1.0.2. The task I execute is `sbt "project frontend" docker:publishLocal`

Comment: Are you building your docker-image on windows? We fixed this with https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/588 using a constant separator. This should be in the next release.

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows. Thanks for your reply. I will try to build this pull locally.